# Doctrine 1 don't return data array correctly on CodeIgniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I'm having some troubles when i get data of one of my table.

I'm using Doctrine 1 + Codeigniter and the problems is that the data obtains only the last one registry.

I don't have define any relation between this tables (OpModelos and AnSimNavTrans) and this is the scenery:

Controller:

```
class Modelos extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($idModelo) {
        $aData['site_description'] = 'AutoDato';
        $aData['site_keywords'] = 'keywords';
        $aData['site_robots'] = 'robots';
        $aData['site_author'] = 'author';

        $modelo = Doctrine::getTable('OpModelo')->find($idModelo);
        $modelo_caract = Doctrine::getTable('anCaractUserMo')->getByModeloId($idModelo);
        $modelos_similares_nav = Doctrine::getTable('OpModelo')->getModeloSimNav($idModelo);

        $aData['modelo'] = $modelo;
        $aData['modelo_caract'] = $modelo_caract;
        $aData['modelos_similares_nav'] = $modelos_similares_nav;

        $aData['view'] = 'modelo/view';

        $this->load->view('template', $aData);
    }
}
```

data table AnSimNavTrans

```
op_modelo_id  cod_mod med_sim
    1           10      0.9
    1           2       0.8
    1           11      0.7
    1           4       0.5
    1           6       0.1
```

Model

```
class OpModeloTable extends Doctrine_Table {

    public function getModeloSimNav($idModelo) {
        $query = Doctrine_Query::create();
        $query->from('AnSimNavTrans');
        $query->where('op_modelo_id = ?', $idModelo);
        $query->orderBy('med_sim DESC');
        $query->limit('3');

        $result = $query->execute();

        return $result->toArray();
    }
}
```

View:

```
print_r($modelos_similares_nav);

Array ( [0] => Array ( [op_modelo_id] => 1 [cod_mod] => 11 [med_sim] => 0.7 ) )
```

As you can see in view, when I get the array of the query, this only show the last record.

What its wrong with this?

Comment: First: it feel strange to me that `OpModeloTable->getModeloSimNav` make a query to `AnSimNavTrans`. Why not using `AnSimNavTransTable` to do that? Second: If you want an array, hydrate with array instead of using `toArray`: `$result = $query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`. Test with this last thing.

Comment: i <3 you!!
your solution works perfectly, but, why? i don't understand why when i execute the query, this return the values without problem, but, my code only show the last records of the query?.
now, respect to first question, after make the custion i change the query to AnSumNavTransTable :)
thanks for you help :)

Comment: So I will posted it as an answer. But I don't know why your solution isn't working ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

It feel strange to me that `OpModeloTable->getModeloSimNav` make a query to `AnSimNavTrans`. Why not using `AnSimNavTransTable` to do that?

**Second:**

If you want an array, hydrate with array instead of using `toArray`:

```
$result = $query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);.
```

Test with this last thing. I don't know why this way is working when your solution doesn't. When taking a look at the code, toArray comment's function says :

> Mimics the result of a $query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

So, maybe it's better to not mimics this function but actually use it..

By the way, using hydration like I told you is better than using `toArray`. The idea behind using a hydration with array is that doctrine won't hydrate objects (and all dependencies). This will save you **lots of time** when the page is loaded.

When using `toArray`, you will hydrate with objects and after convert it to array. You waste lots of time.

It's the first step in a performance issue fixing.